# Can we draw closed path made up of 9 line segments each of which intersects exactly one of the other line segmentsn

Tags: even-and-odd-functions

This problem is taken from MATHEMATICS CIRCLE book

Can anyone tell me how the figure of this problem look like 
Pls elaborate with simplest explanation

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is no, since for every intersection point you would complete the requirement for exactly 2 of the segments, which are, however, 9, an odd number.

Comment: Can't understand Pls elaborate as simple as you can

Comment: Each time a segment crosses another, well, that's it for them - they can't cross anything ever again, since each segment crosses exactly one other. So, for each crossing point, two segments go "out of action" - they are no more included in the possible "crossing mates" of other segments. Then the segments are obviously partitioned to couples that cross, each with its own crossing point. So, the segments must be even. Here, however, they are nine, thus odd. So the answer to this question is negative.

Comment: Excellent explaination sir

Comment: Then you should think about accepting it.