# Can we draw a closed path made up of 9 line segments , each of which intersects exactly one of the other segments?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, parity, closed-graph

The solution given in Fomin's book is as follows.
If such a closed path were possible, then all the line segments could be partitioned into pairs of intersecting segments. But then the number of intersecting segments would have to be even.

How is the first statement true? It seems that we could not have 9 line segments  each of which intersects exactly one other line segment in the first place  because there will be one left out. I cannot understand the meaning of the first statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can line segments in a closed path intersect only one other segment?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843424/how-can-line-segments-in-a-closed-path-intersect-only-one-other-segment)

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778897/can-we-draw-closed-path-made-up-of-9-line-segments-each-of-which-intersects-exac) is another duplicate.

Comment: No, I think you got the meaning, it's just that simple. (A) If we could draw this, each segment would be paired with one other segment, (B) The number of segments would then be even, (C) We have an odd number of segments, which is a contradiction, so it's undrawable.